# NHibernate with Npgsql how to turn off prepared statement

Tags: c#, nhibernate, npgsql

In my application, I am using `nhibernate` and `npgsql`. How can I disable the prepared statement? I tried:

- set maxAutoPrepare to 0 in connection string
- set NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.PrepareSql to false

But it does not work for me.